# Create a pl/sql function & find leap years

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please let me know how to find a leap year through PL/SQL function. Suppose we input any number, how can we find out it is leap year or not?

Comment: The second result while googling, http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_detect_leap_year_function.htm

Answer (score 12):

Try the below function,

```
FUNCTION leap_year_or_not(
         i_year IN NUMBER)
         RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
     l_var VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
     IF TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/02/'||i_year, 'dd/mm/yyyy')), 'DD') = 29 THEN
          l_var := 'Leap Year';
     ELSE
          l_var := 'Not Leap Year';
     END IF;
     RETURN l_var;                 
END;
```

Comment: Let's hear, why it is down voted? Anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: Nice idea for leap year :) just by finding last day of Feb!! +1

Comment: quite usual, you could also count days between start of year and add_months(start of year,12)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, if a year is divisible by 4 without a remainder and not by 100 it's a leap year. But, if the year is divisible by both 4 and 100 without a remainder, it also should be divisible by 400 to be a leap year.

So a function, which will tell you whether a year you've provided is a leap one or not could look like this:

```
 create or replace package utl is
   function is_leap_year(p_year in number) return number;
 end;
/
Package created


create or replace package body utl is
  function is_leap_year(p_year in number) return number is
  begin
     return case
              when ( mod(p_year, 4) = 0 and mod(p_year, 100) <> 0 ) or
                   ( mod(p_year, 400) = 0 ) then 1
              else 0
            end;
  end;
end;
/
Package body created
```

Test case:

```
SQL> select 1999 + level                    as test_year
  2       , utl.is_leap_year(1999 + level)  as is_leap
  3    from dual
  4  connect by level <= 12
  5  ;
```

Result:

```
 TEST_YEAR    IS_LEAP
---------- ----------
      2000          1
      2001          0
      2002          0
      2003          0
      2004          1
      2005          0
      2006          0
      2007          0
      2008          1
      2009          0
      2010          0
      2011          0

12 rows selected
```

Comment: I see as more correct and platform independent