# From date extract year and than find who was born on the leap year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

From table `Client` find out who is born (`date`) on the leap year. 
Table "Client" contains just row " date" and if you select all from date you will get birthdays of all the clients, for example 07.07.98, 04.11.88, and null, because there is no record about that client
The leap year is divisible with 4 and is not divisible with 100. 
When we go

`select date from client;`

we get

```
03.11.73
02.12.74
09.02.85
.......
```

I need to write a query that will extract just the year if that year corresponds required query, in this case, the year like " 1600, 2000 i 2400"

Comment: `extract(year from date)`.

Comment: Divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100 does not mean divisible by 400

Comment: @aleksej, my mistake.. The leap year is divisible with 4 and is not divisible with 100, not 400.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20948031/106261

Comment: @NimChimpsky, i tryed with that link but i cant find the solution

Comment: @GoranBartBartolić: So are you expecting someone to write the whole code for you? Please try to write some code on your own.

Comment: @Nitish, no, i want to write on my own.  I tryed something, but is not good even nearly... select TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/02/'||date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')), 'DD') = 29 
THEN 'Leap Year' else 'Not Leap Year'  from client;

Comment: In NimChimpsky's link date is a number like 1964. In your table, date is in the format `03.11.73`, which most probably is a string. So you'll need to convert it into a date and then extract year from it(0073 or 1973) and then use the above query(which is not syntactically correct). Also please learn the basics first.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the results of `DESCRIBE CLIENT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to find the birth date of anybody who was born on the leap year:

If `date` is of date format

```
select date 
  from client 
 where TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/02/'||to_char(date,'yy'), 'dd/mm/yy')), 'DD') = 29;
```

if `date` is a char:

```
select date 
  from client 
 where TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/02/'||substr(date, 7, 2), 'dd/mm/yy')), 'DD') = 29;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's  the solution, but i'm geting a messege " input value not long enough for date format" . Is possible that this is because my date format is like " 02.03.89" , " 12.01.90" ... ?

Comment: Actually, what type is "date" column? in case it is a varchar, you should remplace my `to_char(date, 'yyyy')` by `substr(date, 7, 2) ` and assume it is current century by replacing the `'yyyy'` by `'yy'`. I changed the answer asuming that.

Comment: "date" column type is date. When I changed " '01/02/'|| " into '01.02.99'||  , and used distinct, i got 322 rows selected. I think that's correct query, but just one question. Displayed data is in format : 01.01.80, that is a leap year, how can I select just the years (1980 in this case )thats appears on the leap year? For example, we have two birthdays on a leap year, 01.08.80 and 18.08.80 , i want to display just " 1980 ". Is that possible, do I have to use extract?

Comment: i tryed this and i got so many years.. But the distinct doesn't work.. select  extract( year from date) as Year
  from Client
 where TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01.02.99'||substr(date, 7, 2), 'dd.mm.yyyy')), 'DD') = 29 order by date asc;

Comment: you must use the distinct on the year only then: `select distinct substr(date, 7, 2)` or `to_char(date,'yy')`

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted the query in the way I wanted to display :

```
select distinct someYear from (select extract(year from date)  sameYear
  from Client
 where TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01.02.99'||substr(date, 7, 2),
 'dd.mm.yyyy')), 'DD') = 29 ) Table order by sameYear asc;
```

Result is :

```
      1912 
      1920 
      1924 
      1932 
      1936 
      1940 
      1944 
      1948 
      1952 
      1956 
      1960 
      1964 
      1968 
      1972 
      1976 
      1980 
      1984 
      1988 
      1992 
      1996 
      2004 
      2008 
      2012
```